# CodeIgniter Form_Validation for uri segments

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I want to use the `form_validation` on values other than `$_POST` parameters. So for example i have this function in a controller

```
public function items($category=NULL, $id=NULL){
    //how do i run $category and $id through form_validation        
}
```

Comment: `form_validation` says it all, it's not meant to validate uri segments. If you want to validate the uri, do it in the `Model` or `Controller`.

Comment: i see post data and uri segments both as a way to pass data from the client to the server. They both need to be validated in a similar way. So why not reuse the `form_validation` functionality?

Comment: Because it makes no sense from a `OOP` point of view. From your perspective (as an example), should `Models` be bundled with a pagination method? They can, and it "makes sense" since you'll eventually need to work that pagination out of returned data from a `Model`, but `Models` aren't supposed to know about pagination, it doesn't belong to them.

Comment: so you're saying I just roll my own validation in the `Controller`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3333/discussion-between-yoda-and-ilia-choly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function someone posted on the CodeIgniter forums that uses the same validation rules as `form_validation`

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/153602/